# How to cause re-render when I change the state using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a component that I am creating which involves two buttons to create a game session. When the game is created by the user, it automatically redirects him to the game session. I also want to allow the re-direct to the session if a game is NOT created by the user but instead, the user 'joins' a so called game session created by another user. My functional component looks as follows:

```
const GameCreate = ({session}) => {
/************** HOOKS *******************************/
    const [sessionLocal, setSessionLocal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSessionLocal(session);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [session]);


/************** EVENT HANDLERS *******************************/
  const createGameSession = (gamesettings) => {
    const { playerLimit, deckId } = gamesettings;
    createSession(.....);//call to back end that populates 'session' props which inturn triggers the 
                         //useEffect hook above
  };

  const joinSetSession = (sessionToJoinIndex) => {
    setSessionLocal(foundgames[sessionToJoinIndex]);
  };

  if (sessionLocal) {
    return <Redirect to="/gamesession" />;
  }

  return profile === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : ( <Fragment>
         <div><p>{profile.name}</p></div>
          <CreateGame // a modal component that calls the createGameSession() as a callback
          // .... some other data is passed to this component
            setGame={(gamesettings) => createGameSession(gamesettings)}
          />
          <JoinGame // a modal component that calls the joinSetSession() as a callback
         // .... some other data is passed to this component
            setSessionToJoin={(sessionToJoinIndex) =>
              joinSetSession(sessionToJoinIndex)
            }
          />
     </Fragment>
       );

};
```

My problem is that at the moment createGameSession is successfully triggering my useEffect (as 'session' is returned as payload from the API). As a result my sessionLocal is also being populated which is successfully causing the re-direct. The same does NOT happen with the joinSetSession as it seems that the useEffect hook does not trigger when the setSessionLocal sets the sessionLocal state. Can someone explain to me why this happening and how I can fix it ? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect hook does not trigger until the value passed in the array which is the second parameter for useEffect hook does not change. In this case session.

And looking at the code, I don't see **joinSetSession** changing or updating the session value. You need to figure out a way to make **joinSetSession** change session value or have the logic not so tightly coupled with sessionLocal variable.

I might suggest using another useState hook which will keep track of joining existing session and basis its value manipulations can be done.

Comment: Thanks. I see now why the re render wont happen. May be i need to find some way to couple the two state changes together.

Comment: I tried making changes by adding 2 useEffect hooks but in vain. Here's my added hooks:
```
  useEffect(() => {
    setSessionsList(foundgames);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [foundgames]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalSession(sessionsList[joinIndex]);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [joinIndex]);
```
Somehow i thought I could trigger render when the index for the array of joinsessions arrays changes. Still doesn't rerender for me.